# Comparing two arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var array1 = [column1,column2,column3,column4];
var array2 = [column1 [empid],column2 [mobno],column4 [place]];
```

- if array1 has any of array2 values. I mean, in above case column1,column2,column4 is there in array1, then remove those values and array1 should have only column3 and then append array1 value with array2.
- after check and remove, now `array1 = [column3]` then append `array1` value with `array2` and finally
- `array2 = [column1 [empid],column2 [mobno],column3,column4 [place]];` it should be in correct index position

is above case possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a library like [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#union), it has functions like `_.union()` that would do what you described. If you don't want to the library you could have a look at their implementation.

Using your example:

```
array2 = _.union(array1, array2);
```

Comment: can you tell me how to use _.union. am getting error: _is not defined

Comment: @Rachel you need to download and import underscore.js into your project. It's not built in to the browser

Comment: @Rachel as I said in my answer, you could have a look in the underscore.js source to see what the `_.union()` function is doing.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use any library then you can do

`for(elem in array2){`

```
    var index = array1.indexOf(array2[elem]);
    if(index > -1)
    array1.splice(index,1);
```

}

array2 = array1.concat(array2).sort();